# C++ iostream not setting eof bit even if gcount returns 0

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I'm developping an application under windows, and i'm using fstreams to read and write to the file.

I'm writing with fstream opened like this :

```
fs.open(this->filename.c_str(), std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
```

and writing with this command

```
fs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e.element), sizeof(T));
```

closing the file after each write with

```
fs.close()
```

Reading with ifstream opened like this :

```
is.open(filename, std::ios::in);
```

and reading with this command :

```
is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e.element), sizeof(T));
```

The write is going fine. However, i read in a loop this way :

```
while(!is.eof())
{
  is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e.element), sizeof(T));
}
```

and the program keeps reading, even though the end of file should be reached. istellg pos is 0, and gcount is equal to 0 too, but the fail bit and eof bit are both ok.

I'm running crazy over this, need some help ...

Comment: "the fail bit and eof bit are both ok" - by this do you mean they are set or not set?

Comment: Never use eof() - take a look at http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/hello-world for an alternative perspective.

Comment: Thanks neil that's interresting, but i think i was indeed relying on the expected behavior, and it still doesn't work. Indeed, after the last read the cursor should be positionned on the 1028th byte. Since the file is 1028 bytes, it's EOF. But it doesn't work. I'd really love to know why

Comment: The flag won't be set until *after* you try to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
while(is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e.element), sizeof(T))) {}
```

Also you should open the `istream` with the `binary` flag as well:

```
is.open(filename, std::ios::in | std:ios::binary);
```

If it reads forever, what does it read? What type is T?

Comment: T is a simple POD type, here something like 
    struct a
    {
      WCHAR b[512];
    }

Your solution works, thank you very much. I really **really** fail to understand while the fail/eof bits are not set though...

Comment: If the answer works and helps you, you should at least accept it (the green tick). You can also vote it up if you think it is a good answer.

Comment: yeah sorry it told me i had to wait 15 secs to vote and i didn't come back in a row.

Also i don't have enough rep yet to upvote. But thanks !